# WSO2 EMM Agent with COSU not using NFC

Tags: cosu, wso2-iot

I have built the latest version of wso2 emm android agent (cdmf-agent-android v3.1.30) and got some initial tests working in BYOD mode with IoT server 3.1.0

When built for COSU it is waiting for provisioning with another device via NFC.  But I want to provision devices without NFC. What options do I have?  Could I trigger programmatically a custom provisioning option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some options to do this, depending on your android version.

I will start with the simplest option. If you have Android 7+ you can use QR Code provisioning, this follows the exact same process as NFC provisioning. You can see some specifications from Google regarding [this](https://developers.google.com/android/work/prov-devices#qr_code_method).

The second option is a bit trickier and requires some custom dev on your side. First thing to to make your device a Device Owner (Which is needed for COSU mode, read up about Device Owner [here](https://sdgsystems.com/blog/android-device-owner)). Using the command: `adb shell dpm set-device-owner org.wso2.iot.agent/org.wso2.iot.agent.services.AgentDeviceAdminReceiver`

Note: Only one device owner can be set, to remove a device owner the device has to be factory reset.

Once this is done you can launch your app using `adb shell am start -n "org.wso2.iot.agent/org.wso2.iot.agent.activities.SplashActivity"`.

The above will get your app to run correctly but now it has to authenticate itself to communicate to the server. When using NFC provisioning an Access Token is delivered in the Extra Bundle as 'android.app.extra.token', you can insert this extra in the launch intent as follows: `adb shell am start -n "org.wso2.iot.agent/org.wso2.iot.agent.activities.SplashActivity" --es android.app.extra.token generated_access_token`. You will have to edit the SpashActivity class to accept this token and follow the general authentication processes built into the app.

This may be a little bit late but I hope it is still helpful!

Some extra information you may appreciate, here is a string representation of the NFC message used, these are the specifications set in the NFC Provisioning App:

`

```
#Thu Apr 12 13:42:11 GMT+02:00 2018
android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_LOCAL_TIME=1523533331087
android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_TIME_ZONE=Asia/Colombo
android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_SKIP_ENCRYPTION=true
android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_WIFI_SECURITY_TYPE=WPA
android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_WIFI_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION=LOCATION_OF_APK
android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_WIFI_SSID="WIFI_SSID_NAME"
android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_LOCALE=en_US
android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_CHECKSUM=E8PtiqUOcqKi5IXeRBF-5Br0zXg
android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_ADMIN_EXTRAS_BUNDLE=\#admin extras bundle\n\#Thu Apr 12 13\:42\:11 GMT+02\:00 2018\nandroid.app.extra.token\=GENERATED_ACCESS_TOKEN\n
android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_NAME=org.wso2.iot.agent
```

`

An example of a QR Code representation would be:

`

```
{
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME": "org.wso2.iot.agent/org.wso2.iot.agent.services.AgentDeviceAdminReceiver",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_SIGNATURE_CHECKSUM": "CSGeivCEHdJrPT0qy4W67LZSy32Fus7GyUn0jE5o028",
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION": "APK_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION",
    "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_SKIP_ENCRYPTION": false,
    "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_NAME": "org.wso2.iot.agent",
    "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_ADMIN_EXTRAS_BUNDLE": {
        "android.app.extra.token":"GENERATED_ACCESS_TOKEN"
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Thanks for this. Exactly what I was looking for.